# django/ruby on rails is community or enterprise based

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, frameworks

i wonder if django has a community or an enterprise behind it for devlopement?

the same with rails.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both open-source projects.  They both have large communities, but are not enterprise backed.  I believe that Rails will have more backing as a framework while Django will have more backing because of Python.

If you're looking for Enterprise-y-ness, look at Java EE or the Microsoft stack.  If you're looking for something to get a project off the ground quickly, RoR or Django are pretty nice.

Comment: i never understood why i have to use java EE if i want "enterprise-y-ness". what can they give me that php/ruby/python cant?

Comment: In my experience, enterprise software tends to be deployed in more than one setting.  You might want to have a desktop application for  your accounting software, but then use the same data in web-based reporting.  Using a common language/framework for the Desktop, Web, embedded systems, etc, can allow you to reuse more code thus requiring less code.  A web-focused framework like RoR or Django could be modified to work in the same sort of environment, but it would take a lot of development to modify a framework instead of using one for your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Django, but Ruby on Rails was first developed by David Heinemeier Hansson for the [37signals](http://37signals.com/) company. And the 37signals still sponsors the development of Ruby on Rails and pays the wages for four out of eight [core](http://rubyonrails.org/core) developers. And the other ones also work for companies who have an interest in bringing RoR forward.